# Ajax return wrong result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two arrays. 1 is empty and other have 5 items. I  want to count them and display it.

i send ajax request like this :

```
function countTrash()
    {
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "count_trash_delete.php",
               data: "action=1",
               success: function(response){
                          $("#badge3").html(response);
                        }
       });
    }




function countRemove()
    {
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "count_trash_delete.php",
               data: "action=2",
               success: function(response){
                          $("#badge2").html(response);
                        }
       });
    }
```

My count_trash_delete.php looks like this

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = 1;
}else{
    $action = 2;
}

if($action === 1){

    $trash_arr = file_get_contents('trash_bots.json');
    $trash_arr = json_decode($trash_arr);
    $number_of_trashed = count($trash_arr);

    echo $number_of_trashed;

}elseif($action === 2){

    $remove_arr = file_get_contents('remove_bots.json');
    $remove_arr = json_decode($remove_arr);

    if(!empty($remove_arr)){        
    $number_of_removed = count($remove_arr);    
        echo $number_of_removed;        
    }else{
        echo 'Empty';
    }   
}
```

When i get response  both are 5. Which i cant understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking the page to do the same thing, so it does the same thing. This is the problem code:

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = 1;
}else{
    $action = 2;
}
```

It doesn't matter what the **value** of `$_GET['action']` is in that code, if it's there at all you'll set `$action` to `1` and if it isn't there you'll set `$action` to `2`. Since you're always passing `action`, the page always does the same thing.

You probably want to set `$action` to the *value* of `$_GET['action']`:

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = (int)$_GET['action'];
}else{
    $action = /*...some appropriate default number...*/;
}
```

Comment: ohh .. i cant belive i did not saw that . thanks a lot